# Python - replacing each list character equal to key of dictionary with value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, replace

I have to replace each alphabetical character in the list with the corresponding value of the key. For example 'h' from 'hello' needs to change to 'u' which is the dictionary value of the dictionary key 'h':

My code:

```
list = ["hello", "1234kuku"]
dict = {'a': 'n', 'e': 'r','h': 'u', 'l': 'y', 'o': 'b', 'u': 'h','k': 'x'}

def encode(list, dict):
for word in list:
    for key, value in dict.items():       
        for char in word:
            if char == key:                        
                list = [w.replace(char, value) for w in list]
return(list)

print(encode(list,dict))
```

My problem is that I am able to get this:

```
['hryyb', '1234xhxh']
```

but I need this:

```
['uryyb', '1234xhxh']
```

I know the issue has something to do with the loop because it basically changes the 'hello' to 'uryyb' but after looping to the second list item and changing '1234kuku' it changes 'uryyb' to 'hryyb'.

Comment: try this oneliner instead: `result = ["".join(dct.get(x,"") for x in s) for s in lst]`. It avoids the O(n**3) or O(n**4) complexity of your failing program

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre a little adjustment `dct.get(x,x)` numbers should be kept

Comment: update your indenting

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre that oneliner ommitts the numbers 1234 from kuku, so it outputs xhxh instead of 1234xhxh. Thank you though!

Comment: Ah just saw @rioV8 comment, yes that dct.get(x,x) helped to keep the numbers in. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has just the thing, `maketrans`. Example:

```
# `list` and `dict` shadow built-in primitive types. Use different names
strings = ["hello", "1234kuku"]
d = {'a': 'n', 'e': 'r','h': 'u', 'l': 'y', 'o': 'b', 'u': 'h','k': 'x'}

tr = str.maketrans(d)
result = [s.translate(tr) for s in strings]
```

Comment: Amazing. Today I learned.

Comment: OMG! After 10 hours of tweaking around to figure this out, all I needed was MAKETRANS! I have never heard of that, today I learned, too! Thank you so much! It worked!